# Terraform - AWS codepipeline attaching stages

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

Is it possible to define  a codepipeline on terraform an attach stages to it in a file different from the codepipeline declaration

Answer (score 1):

Normally yes, terraform reads in all the files in the directory, and loads all modules as well. If you use modules to define the pipeline and a separate one for the stages, you'll need to pass the pipeline id in a variable to the staging module.

**BUT** Stages are attributes of a codepipeline resources, And currently there is no codepipeline stage resource to attach to a codepineline resource like you could for ebs volumes for ec2 instances.

> The files loaded must end in either .tf or .tf.json to specify the format that is in use. Otherwise, the files are ignored. Multiple file formats can be present in the same directory; it is okay to have one Terraform configuration file be Terraform syntax and another be JSON.

https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/modules.html

https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/load.html

https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/outputs.html

https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/codepipeline.html